# How to upgrade kernel of a server running syslog-ng

Tags: linux, upgrade, syslog-ng

I run a server with syslog-ng to collect my network logs, and by receiving a security bulletin alert I have to upgrade this server.

This question is what is the strategy to upgrade this machine, knowing that many other machine's logs depend on this and on an upgrade may be we are faced of many reboots ?

what is the comportment of other syslog when syslog-ng is not running.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)